# Maximum $n$ such that ${n \choose k} \,2^{1 - {k \choose 2}} < 1$ (where $k$ is a constant)

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, binomial-coefficients, ramsey-theory, probabilistic-method

Maximum value of $n$ such that the expression given below does not exceed 1. ($k$ is a constant)

$${n \choose k} 2^{1 - {k \choose 2}}  < 1$$

Any hints on how to approach this problem.

Thanks.

**Edit:**

I tried doing the problem this way.

$${n \choose k} < \frac{n^k}{k!}$$
$${n \choose k} 2^{1 - {k \choose 2}} < \frac{n^k}{k!}2^{1 - {k \choose 2}}$$
$$\frac{n^k}{k!}2^{1 - {k \choose 2}} < 1 \Rightarrow n < \sqrt[k]{\frac{k!}{2^{1 - {k \choose 2}}}}$$
But, still $n_{max}$ can be greater than $\sqrt[k]{\frac{k!}{2^{1 - {k \choose 2}}}}$. How can i get the least upper bound for $n$.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried?

Comment: It's unlikely that you can get the exact value.  This will involve solving a $k$-th degree polynomial equation for an arbitrary $k$.  There is no known method to  algebraically solve large polynomial equations.  What is wrong with your bound?  Why isn't it good enough?

Comment: k is constant. I am very sorry for incomplete question. @Batominovski

Comment: Doesn't matter.  You are not giving us a very specific $k$ like: $k=2$, $k=3$, or $k=4$ (and for such $k$'s the problem is very trivial anyhow).  If $k\geq 5$, then good luck.  No known general way to solve a quintic.  The only good approximation is probably $$n_\max \approx 2^{\frac{k-1}{2}}\,\frac{k}{\text{e}}\,.$$

Comment: can you tell me how you got the approximate value? @Batominovski

Comment: Well, I used a very rough estimation $k!\approx\left(\frac{k}{\text{e}}\right)^k$.  After some numerical test, it seems that $$2^{\frac{k-1}{2}}\,\frac{k}{\text{e}}< n_\max <2^{\frac{k}{2}}\,\frac{k}{\text{e}}\,,$$ at least for $k\geq 7$.  Maybe, $$n_\max\approx 2^{\frac{k-3}{2}}\,k$$ will be even a better approximation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I shall prove that, for a positive integer $k$, the maximum natural number $n$, denoted by $n_k$, such that
$$\binom{n}{k}\leq 2^{\binom{k}{2}-1}$$
satisfies 
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\,\frac{n_k}{k\,2^{\frac{k}{2}}}=\frac{1}{\text{e}\sqrt{2}}\,.\tag{*}$$
I also provide some bounds for the value of $n_k$.

First, we note that
$$\frac{\left(n_k-\frac{k-3}{2}\right)^k}{k!}>\binom{n_k+1}{k}>2^{\binom{k}{2}-1}\,,$$
where we have applied the AM-GM Inequality
$$\begin{align}(n_k+2-k)&(n_k+3-k)\cdots (n_k)(n_k+1)\\
&\leq \left(\frac{(n_k+2-k)+(n_k+3-k)+\ldots +(n_k)+(n_k+1)}{k}\right)^k
\\&=\left(n_k-\frac{k-3}{2}\right)^k\,.\end{align}$$
That is,
$$n_k-\frac{k-3}{2}>\sqrt[k]{2^{\binom{k}{2}-1}\,k!}=2^{\frac{k-1}{2}}\,\sqrt[k]{\frac{k!}{2}}\geq 2^{\frac{k-1}{2}}\left(\frac{\pi k}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2k}}\,\left(\frac{k}{\text{e}}\right)>2^{\frac{k-1}{2}}\,\left(\frac{k}{\text{e}}\right)\,,$$
where we have used the [Stirling Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) $$k!\geq \sqrt{2\pi k}\left(\frac{k}{\text{e}}\right)^k\,.$$
This shows that $$n_k>2^{\frac{k-1}{2}}\,\left(\frac{k}{\text{e}}\right)+\frac{k-3}{2}\,.$$

Now, 
$$\frac{(n_k+1-k)^k}{k!}<\binom{n_k}{k}\leq 2^{\binom{k}{2}-1}\,.$$
This gives
$$n_k-(k-1)<\sqrt[k]{2^{\binom{k}{2}-1}\,k!}\leq 2^{\frac{k-1}{2}}\,\left(\frac{\text{e}^2k}{4}\right)^{\frac{1}{2k}}\,\left(\frac{k}{\text{e}}\right)\,,$$
in which we have used the Stirling approximation
$$k!\leq \sqrt{\text{e}^2k}\,\left(\frac{k}{\text{e}}\right)^k\,.$$
That is,
$$n_k<2^{\frac{k-1}{2}}\,\left(\frac{k}{\text{e}}\right)\,\Biggl(1+O\left(\frac{\ln(k)}{k}\right)\Biggr)+k-1\,,$$
noting that
$$\left(\frac{\text{e}^2k}{4}\right)^{\frac{1}{2k}}=1+\frac{\ln(k)}{2k}+\frac{1-\ln(2)}{k}+O\left(\left(\frac{\ln(k)}{k}\right)^2\right)=1+O\left(\frac{\ln(k)}{k}\right)\,.$$

In conclusion, we have
$$2^{\frac{k-1}{2}}\,\left(\frac{k}{\text{e}}\right)+\frac{k-3}{2}<n_k<2^{\frac{k-1}{2}}\,\left(\frac{k}{\text{e}}\right)\,\Biggl(1+O\left(\frac{\ln(k)}{k}\right)\Biggr)+k-1\,.$$
This proves (*).  In fact, we can also show that, for all $k\geq 22$, 
$$2^{\frac{k-1}{2}}\,\left(\frac{k+\frac{1}{2}\,\ln(k)+\frac{1}{5}}{\text{e}}\right)<n_k<2^{\frac{k-1}{2}}\,\left(\frac{k+\frac{1}{2}\,\ln(k)+\frac{1}{3}}{\text{e}}\right)\,,$$
using
$$\left(\frac{\pi k}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2k}}=1+\frac{\ln(k)}{2k}+\frac{\ln(\pi)-\ln(2)}{2k}+O\left(\left(\frac{\ln(k)}{k}\right)^2\right)$$
and
$$\frac{1}{5}<\frac{\ln(\pi)-\ln(2)}{2}<1-\ln(2)<\frac{1}{3}\,.$$
Anyhow, the best approximator of $n_k$ is still $m_k:=2^{\frac{k-1}{2}}\,\sqrt[k]{\dfrac{k!}{2}}$, albeit being trickier to calculate, since we have
$$m_k+\frac{k-3}{2}< n_k < m_k+k-1\,.$$